# Shiny dashboard with conditional plotOut

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am just starting with shiny and dashboard, so any help is greatly appreciated!

I have a shinydashboard app displaying one row with two elements: A `tabBox` on the left with two `tabPanel`s, and a `box` on the right (to display a plot).

What I want is to display a particular plot in the box depending on the active `tabPanel`. The plot should be *not clickable* when the first tab is active, but *clickable* when the second tab is active.

My problem is that I only know how to set up the clickable property in the `ui` through the `plotOutput` function using the option `click = "plot_click"`. But this sets both plots as clickable. Of course, removing the option `click = "plot_click"` sets both plots as not-clickable. How can I make the clickable property depend on the active tab?

**What I tried:** Place an `if` statement inside `box()` such that, depending on the id of the `tabPanel`, it would activate the option `click = "plot_click"` for the correct plot. I failed at this.

Here's the code. You can play with either plot by (un)commenting the desired plot inside `box()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Conditional plotOutput click", titleWidth = 450),

  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE), 

  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(
      tabBox(title = "Choose tab", id = "choose.tab", height = 250, selected = "Automatic", 
             tabPanel(title = "Automatic", id = "auto", sliderInput("slider", "Nobs:", 1, 10, 5)), 
             tabPanel(title = "Manual", id = "man")
      ), 

      box(title = "Plot", solidHeader = TRUE, 
          # plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)                     # Try me!
          plotOutput("plot2", height = 250, click = "plot_click") # Or me!
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(123)

  react.vals <- reactiveValues( 
    df     = data.frame(x = numeric(), y = numeric()), 
    plot1  = ggplot(), 
    plot2  = ggplot()
  )

  # Plot 1 - Automatic scatterplot:
  observe({
    scatter.data     <- data.frame(x = runif(input$slider), y = runif(input$slider))
    react.vals$plot1 <- ggplot(scatter.data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(color = "red", size = 4) + 
      scale_x_continuous("x", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) +
      scale_y_continuous("y", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
  })
  observeEvent(react.vals$plot1, { 
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ react.vals$plot1 })
  })

  # Plot 2 - Manual scatterplot through clicking:
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    new.point     <- data.frame(x = input$plot_click$x,
                                y = input$plot_click$y)
    react.vals$df <- rbind(react.vals$df, new.point)
  })
  observe({
    react.vals$plot2 <- ggplot(react.vals$df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(color = "red", size = 4) + 
      scale_x_continuous("x", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) +
      scale_y_continuous("y", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
  })
  observeEvent(react.vals$plot2, { 
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({ react.vals$plot2 })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in advance,
jorge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uiOutput` to define the characteristics of `plotOutput` according to the active `tabPanel`. Below is your example adapted with `uiOutput`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Conditional plotOutput click", titleWidth = 450),

  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE), 

  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(
      tabBox(title = "Choose tab", id = "choose_tab", height = 250, selected = "Automatic", 
             tabPanel(title = "Automatic", id = "auto", sliderInput("slider", "Nobs:", 1, 10, 5)), 
             tabPanel(title = "Manual", id = "man")
      ), 

      box(title = "Plot", solidHeader = TRUE, 
          uiOutput("test")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(123)

  react.vals <- reactiveValues( 
    df     = data.frame(x = numeric(), y = numeric()), 
    plot1  = ggplot(), 
    plot2  = ggplot()
  )

  observe({
    if (input$choose_tab == "Automatic") {
      output$test <- renderUI({
        plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)
      })
    }
    else if(input$choose_tab == "Manual") {
      output$test <- renderUI({
        plotOutput("plot2", height = 250, click = "plot_click")
      })
    }
  })

  # Plot 1 - Automatic scatterplot:
  observe({
    scatter.data     <- data.frame(x = runif(input$slider), y = runif(input$slider))
    react.vals$plot1 <- ggplot(scatter.data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(color = "red", size = 4) + 
      scale_x_continuous("x", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) +
      scale_y_continuous("y", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
  })
  observeEvent(react.vals$plot1, { 
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ react.vals$plot1 })
  })

  # Plot 2 - Manual scatterplot through clicking:
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    new.point     <- data.frame(x = input$plot_click$x,
                                y = input$plot_click$y)
    react.vals$df <- rbind(react.vals$df, new.point)
  })
  observe({
    react.vals$plot2 <- ggplot(react.vals$df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(color = "red", size = 4) + 
      scale_x_continuous("x", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) +
      scale_y_continuous("y", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) + 
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
  })
  observeEvent(react.vals$plot2, { 
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot({ react.vals$plot2 })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:** Fixed a small typo in the R code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, [bretauv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11598948/bretauv), this solves it!

I still needed to add two final changes to the code to have *exactly* what I wanted:

- Remove the plotOutput() inside `box` (not needed anymore).
- Change `plot2` to `plot1` inside the first `renderUI()` call.

Perhaps you want to edit your answer using these tips for future reference.

Thanks a lot! I've upvoted this answer.

Comment: I edited my answer, if it is what you want, you can delete this answer

Comment: One change is still missing:

plotOutput("plot1", height = 250, click = "plot_click")

should be 

plotOutput("plot2", height = 250, click = "plot_click")

Comment: what should I change? can't you edit my post yourself?

Comment: approved and corrected a small thing. Check that the code works and then delete this answer